# Why my tests succeed without a running mongodb instance?

Tags: spring-boot

My app uses mongodb and I have bunch tests that save/query and update data.

I run my tests without a mongodb instance and they all pass! why?

Is this a known feature? what is it called?

Can someone please point me to the bit of documentation that confirms this?

Comment: Not a clue mate. Share some code! :)

Comment: thanks, not sure what share, the tests are passing without a running mongodb, i debug the code and on evaluation of calls i get responses as if the mongodb is running on my system but i know it isn't, so seems to me that spring magic is running and internal instance somehow, just wanted to check if this is a known feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Spring Boot will use an Embedded (in memory) version of Mongo. I'm not sure if this is enabled by default, or if you need to add an extra dependency.

See this page: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb

Comment: turns out by merely including testCompile("de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.2.0") you get an embedded instance I was assuming you need to use @DataMongoTest as well but not the case by the looks of it, cheers